# How to efficiently retrieve data via WMI

Tags: c#, wpf, wmi

I'm working on application which connects to remote hosts and retrieve the metrics like CPU utilization, RAM usage, Disk load, ... In order to connect remotely and retrieve such metrics I use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI). I create WQL query for each metric.  For example, to access 4 types metrics I use 4 different WQL queries and this lead to some delays in whole monitoring process. My question is that, is there any way to use only one WQL (i.e. use only 1 remote connection attempt) and then retrieve the necessary data (metrics) from the result of that WQL query? I'm looking forward to your replies. Thanks.

Just to be more precise about how well my application works: it takes around **6 seconds** to connect to **3 hosts** and collect **2 different metrics** from each of them. Is it a normal performance ratio?

The way how I use WQL to get how much RAM is available:

```
string DomainPath = "\someserver.com\root\cimv2";
List<string> WQLresult = new List<string>();
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(DomainPath, "SELECT FreePhysicalMemory FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" );

try
{
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
    {
        WQLresult.Add(obj["FreePhysicalMemory"].ToString().Trim());
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

I also use Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor class for getting CPU data and Win32_PingStatus class for response data. As can be seen, there are 3 different classes. Question is that, is it possible to get these data by using only 1 WQL  ?

Comment: What metric are you retrieving? Could you show us some code/queries?

Comment: Please, have a look at the topic, I added the code and metrics I want to use.

Comment: efficient relative to what? ;)

Comment: You are getting everything '*' try specifying just the info you're after.

Comment: Erno, thanks for your advice, I corrected the WQL query. However, it didn't made any change in perfomance. still slow :(

Comment: Did you have a look at this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx#ECAA Question 11. You might be able to speed it up a bit by using a where clause or by using `WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY`

Comment: I use where clause where it is necessary. The solution on which I work is threading. Maybe this will help me.